# Sinch framework bug in 3.9.2

Tags: sinch

Ok guys so... I've updated to 3.9.2 hoping they have solved the callbacks ( didEnd, inProggress, didAnswer ) which are not working in their examples either.

Problem is now it fails to compile.. so I've did another project, using `Pod` ofcourse, installed the latest version, and same error comes up.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CMBlockBufferCreateContiguous", referenced from:
      webrtc::H264CMSampleBufferToAnnexBBuffer(opaqueCMSampleBuffer, bool, rtc::Buffer, webrtc::RTPFragmentationHeader**) in Sinch(libSinch-dist.a-i386-master.o)
```

Googled a bit, they say some framework might be missing from the `build phases` suggested to add `QuartzCore.framework`.

So I've did ( I'm using a bridge in Swift )

Everything works fine with the previous 3.7.1 version ( if I recall correctly ) but this one.. just gives me an error even when I have a clean new project.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bug in our cocoa framework, we will release a new tomorrow or the day after

Mean while you can add these by hand

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's now been fixed in version 3.9.3